# MySQL sum based on complex discount

Tags: mysql

I am struggling to solve the following issue.
I have 3 tables, sh_product, sh_discount_class and sh_shipping_lines like the ones below:

sh_product:

```
idp  | product  | qMin  | discount_class  | pallet_class_id_int
1      product 1  10      1                 2
2      product 2  5       1                 0
```

sh_discount_class

```
discount_id  | title  | description  | discount_value
1              5%       5% tax         0.05
```

sh_shipping_lines

```
id  | sh_id  |  idp  | quantity  | value
1     49        1      10          120
2     49        2      1           240
```

Basically, I would like to sum all values based on the following criteria:

1. whenever the `quantity` from `sh_shipping_lines` is greater than the
   `qMin` of the product from the `sh_product` apply the corresponding
   discount from sh_discount_class
2. whenever the product from has a `pallet_class_id_int` declared, means
       that the specific product is double as quantity than the `idp` corresponding with `pallet_class_id_int`. Actually the `pallet_class_id_int` represent the `idp` of another product from the table

So, in my case, the total sum should be (1440 - 5%) = 1368
I have tried to work with the following select, but still it doesn't calculate the total value as it should

```
SELECT DISTINCT sh_shipping_lines.idp, sh_discount_class.discount_value, sh_discount_class.description, 
                          SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity) as total, sh_product.qMin, 
                          if(sh_product.qMin>0 AND sh_product.qMin<SUM(if(sh_product.pallet_class_id_int>0, 2*sh_shipping_lines.quantity, sh_shipping_lines.quantity)), 
                                SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value - SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value*sh_discount_class.discount_value, 
                                SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value) as val 
                      FROM sh_shipping_lines 
                      LEFT JOIN sh_product ON sh_product.idp = sh_shipping_lines.idp 
                      LEFT JOIN sh_discount_class ON sh_discount_class.discount_id = sh_product.discount_class 
                      WHERE sh_id=49 
                      GROUP BY sh_shipping_lines.idp
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
idp  | discount_value  | description  | total  |  qMin  | val
1      0.05              product 1      10        10      1140
2      0.05              product 2      1         5        228
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired result in the same format as above? And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: hi, I have edited the question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added little fix to your query (with the qMin and remove DISTINCT - I don`t think you need it). I suppose qMin column in sh_product is the minimum quantity of a given product that triggers discount? So the IF should be:

```
sh_product.qMin <= SUM
```

And the quantity of the product with idp 2 is 1 (as seen in sh_shipping_lines table), so that`s why discount is not triggered for the second product in the sh_shipping_lines.
So the IF is correct for product 1 but product 2 enters in the ELSE that's why
the final sum is 1380.

```
SELECT sh_shipping_lines.idp, sh_discount_class.discount_value, sh_discount_class.description,
SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity) AS total, sh_product.qMin, SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value*sh_discount_class.discount_value,
    IF(sh_product.qMin>0 AND sh_product.qMin <= SUM(IF(sh_product.pallet_class_id_int>0, 2*sh_shipping_lines.quantity, sh_shipping_lines.quantity)), 
            SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value - SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value*sh_discount_class.discount_value, 
            SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value
    ) AS val

FROM sh_shipping_lines

LEFT JOIN sh_product ON sh_product.idp = sh_shipping_lines.idp
LEFT JOIN sh_discount_class ON sh_discount_class.discount_id = sh_product.discount_class

WHERE sh_id=49
GROUP BY sh_shipping_lines.idp
```

The result of this query is:

```
idp discount_value  description total   qMin    val
1   0.05    5% tax  10  10  1140.0000
2   0.05    5% tax  1   5   240.00
```

**May be this updated version should work**. It`s very ugly but it works for the given input:

```
SELECT  sh_shipping_lines.idp, sh_discount_class.discount_value, sh_discount_class.description,
SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity) AS total, sh_product.qMin, relatedQuantity, 
    IF(sh_product.qMin > 0 AND 
            (
                sh_product.qMin <= sh_shipping_lines.quantity 
                OR 
                sh_product.qMin <= (IF(sh_product.pallet_class_id_int=0, relatedQuantity, sh_shipping_lines.quantity))
            ),
            SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value - SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value*sh_discount_class.discount_value, 
            SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value
    ) AS val

FROM sh_shipping_lines

LEFT JOIN sh_product ON sh_product.idp = sh_shipping_lines.idp
LEFT JOIN sh_discount_class ON sh_discount_class.discount_id = sh_product.discount_class

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT relatedResult.idp AS originalIdp, sh_shipping_lines.idp, sh_shipping_lines.quantity*2 AS relatedQuantity
    FROM
    (
        SELECT sh_shipping_lines.*, prod.idp AS relatedIdp
        FROM sh_product
        JOIN sh_shipping_lines ON sh_shipping_lines.idp=sh_product.idp
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT idp, pallet_class_id_int FROM sh_product) AS prod ON prod.pallet_class_id_int=sh_product.idp
        WHERE sh_shipping_lines.sh_id=49
    ) as relatedResult
    LEFT JOIN sh_shipping_lines ON sh_shipping_lines.idp=relatedResult.relatedIdp
) AS result ON result.originalIdp=sh_shipping_lines.idp

WHERE sh_id=49
GROUP BY sh_shipping_lines.idp;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this result I also receive when running my query.. Actually, I would like the result to be exactly like in the result presented

Comment: Yesy, I understand, but the IF statement is the reason you don't receive the wanted result

    `code`sh_product.qMin <= SUM(IF(sh_product.pallet_class_id_int>0, 2*sh_shipping_lines.quantity, sh_shipping_lines.quantity))

In sh_shipping_lines you have only One quantity of product 2, so that's why your IF hit
`code`SUM(sh_shipping_lines.quantity)*sh_shipping_lines.value) as val

So the quantity for product 2 does not satisfy qMin to receive discount for this product.

Comment: Let me explain it better, maybe it will help more. There are 2 conditions. The first one says that you get a discount if the product quantity on a line is greater then qMin. That's what you and I already got. The second conditions states that, if the pallet_class_id_int is found in a product decalaration, then the discount could be applied if the qMin of the product with idp=pallet_class_id_int is less than the sum of quantities of the both products.